# SQL Server : non-strict WHERE query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to perform a `Select` query on a table that return the value of a column if at least all its required "X" options are validated, even if at the end there are more options.

```
NAME |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D   |  E  |
------------------------------------
BOB           X     X     X   
TOM     X     X     X 
WILL                X     X      X
```

For example: BOB needs to have at least Option B, C and D to be valid. What I would like is to have a query to return BOB if at least B, C and D are true , whatever the value of E or A (even is there are True). A query with B=true, C=true, D=true and A=true should return BOB as well.

So a query like

```
Select 
    Name
From 
    Table
Where 
    A = True and B = True and C = True and D = True
```

that return BOB (because B,C and D are true), and TOM (because A,B and C are True), but no WILL because it needs E=true.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the table.  Look at your logic.  They don't match.

Comment: try like this where clause. `Where (A=True or B=True or C=True or D=True) and not E=True`

Comment: you want to check only only first 3 column value? Like A,B,C or B,C,D or C,D,E.

Comment: So, what's your input? Do you have nullable parameters named @a..@e? Do your table contain null values or zeros/false?

Comment: Do you want to write a dynamic query for every combination or just want to get answer from your sample?

Comment: It looks to me like you're looking for a form of relational division - searches on that term may find you some useful resources - but usually in such situations, it would be easier if the values to work against were all contained in a single column - are your values actually spread across multiple columns or have you already performed some form of pivot in the belief that it would help solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you need three different conditions to be evaluated and if any one of it is true the name is selected.

Here is the query, from what was provided (change the table name and the "True" in the where clauses)

```
Select 
    Name
From 
    Table
Where 
    (B = True and C = True and D = True)
    or (A = True and B = True and C = True)
    or (C = True and D = True and E = True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I can't use 'Or' because in the example BOB needs the Option A and B and C, and i don't mind the value of the other columns (False are true). My example is simple, but the real problem is a larger table (10 column, 20 lines). My input are variables, basically it is a set of options available (A,B,C,D,E) and i need to know which name is satisfied by the set of input option based on the table. The input can be 3 (A,B,C or A,C,D or ....), or more.

Comment: In the real life problem i don't know how many input i have, it is a combination of 1 to 20 values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments!
Yes Damien i think  relational division may help.
 Maybe i can change a bit the structure with 2 tables:

1 table that list the options required for each user to be valid:
t_name

```
Name | Opt1 | opt2 | opt3 | opt4|
================================
BOB  |  B   |  C   |  D   |     |
---------------------------------
TOM  |  A   |  B   |  C   |     |
---------------------------------
WILL |  C   |  D   |  E   |     |
---------------------------------
```

One Table that can be updated by True or False depending if the Option is send as paramtre or not, if the option is sent its value is true (so this table has to be updated by each request to list the options available)

t_option

```
Option | Status| 
================
 A     | True  |
----------------
 B     |  True |
----------------
 C     |  True |
----------------
 D     |  True |
----------------
 E     |  false|
----------------
```

So the query can be something like that:

```
SELECT name FROM t_name 
WHERE opt1 IN (SELECT option FROM t_option WHERE status=True)
AND opt2 IN (SELECT option FROM t_option WHERE status=True)
AND opt3 IN (SELECT option FROM t_option WHERE status=True)
AND opt4 IN (SELECT option FROM t_option WHERE status=True)
```

but i have to be sure that opt is not null (in the example opt4 is null)